# windowShouldClose reporting unresolved identifier

Tags: swift, macos, core-data

I'm trying to trigger a save of my CoreData on a window close as its only a single window application.

I've got the following code in my viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if windowShouldClose(self) {
       saveValues()
    }

}

override func viewDidAppear() {
    super.viewDidAppear()
    self.view.window?.delegate = self
}
```

however im still getting the following error

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'windowShouldClose'
```

Any advice as to why i'm still getting this error after declaring the window delegate as self?

Comment: Is the big 'L' in 'windowShouldCLose' a typo here or in your code?

Comment: Just a typo, My bad!

Comment: **Never** call delegate methods including `will`, `did` and `should` by yourself. They are called by the operating system. Implement the delegate method and put your code in there.

Comment: So if i wanted something to occur when the window is being closed, is that not possible?

Comment: @chrono If you want something to happen when a window is being closed, put your code into the appropriate delegate method. Why would you want to call windowShouldClose while a view is being loaded? Makes no sense from the framework point of view.

Comment: A lack of fully understanding what is going on is why ;) Still a relative noob to this, so I'm doing my best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the delegate in `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   self.view.window?.delegate = self
}
```

and implement the delegate method

```
func windowWillClose(notification: NSNotification) {
   saveValues()
}
```

`windowShouldClose` is different. It asks for permission to close the window and expects a boolean return value.

Comment: This did the trick. I had to put the self.view.window?.delegate = self into the viewDidAppear(), but once i did that everything triggered as expected!